# My Arduino IDE won't compile even simple sketches suddenly... How can I fix that??? this is the error message I get... I did work well at first!

Tags: arduino-uno

```
private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/daniellecomte/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:mega:cpu=atmega2560 -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0042 -ide-version=10805 -build-path /var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_880660 -warnings=all -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.1.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2 -verbose /var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/untitled1415726107.tmp/sketch_may19a/sketch_may19a.ino
/private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/8AC1112E-019A-430D-A268-5BEDD561B4FC/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/daniellecomte/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:mega:cpu=atmega2560 -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0042 -ide-version=10805 -build-path /var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_880660 -warnings=all -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.1.1 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2 -verbose /var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/untitled1415726107.tmp/sketch_may19a/sketch_may19a.ino
Using board 'mega' from platform in folder: /Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21
Detecting libraries used...
"/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/variants/mega" "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_880660/sketch/sketch_may19a.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
Generating function prototypes...
"/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/variants/mega" "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_880660/sketch/sketch_may19a.ino.cpp" -o "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_880660/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
fork/exec /Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++: no such file or directory
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.
```

Comment: What update did you do just before it broke?

Answer (score 1):

> avr-g++: no such file or directory

Try downloading the IDE again. It looks like it has lost sight of where the compiler is. Preferably not a nightly build but one of the stable versions.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates something has gone wrong with your Arduino AVR Boards installation. To make sure it has been fully uninstalled you need to take some drastic action. Be aware this is somewhat advanced and will remove all boards you have installed via Boards Manager:

1. Click the link on the line following **File > Preferences > More preferences can be edited directly in the file**. This will open the `/Users/daniellecomte/Library/Arduino15` folder.
2. Delete all files and folders under the Arduino15 folder except for preferences.txt. Please be very careful when deleting things from your computer. When in doubt, back up!
3. Restart the Arduino IDE

Verify that you can now compile for your board before reinstalling any packages via Boards Manager.

Comment: You were absolutely correct... it works now...  many many thanks sir!

Comment: @DanielLecomte Since you agree this answer helped, please "accept" it so that the Stack Exchange software does not keep prompting for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

recommended is to install Arduino AVR Boards newest version through this simple steps, go to Tools -> Boards -> Board Manager -> Install "Arduino AVR Boards (X.Y.Z).